# How can I make my search function case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, mysql, electron

I'm making an Electron project but I'm having problems with the search function and I can't find a solution, hope you can help me.

I made a simple search function where a table is filled with the results, it works with the `name`, `lastname`, `ID`, `email`, etc. But there's a problem with the `name` and `lastname`, is case sensitive.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa2G8.jpg)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhnOg.jpg)

Here's the code:

```
function buscar()
{
    var busqueda = document.getElementById("busqueda").value;

    con.query("SELECT * FROM candidata", function (err, result, fields)
    {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        var tam = result.length;
        var text;

        for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
        {   
            if((busqueda == result[i].nom_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ci_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ape_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ocu_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].email_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].mun_can) 
            || ((busqueda == result[i].nom_can+" "+result[i].ape_can)))
            {
                text += '<tbody>';
                text += '<tr>';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].ci_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].nom_can;
                text += ' ';
                text += result[i].ape_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].fky_cat;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].mun_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].est_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += '</td>';
                text += '</tr>';
                text += '</tbody>';
            }   
            document.getElementById("find").innerHTML= text;
        }
    });
}
```

I need to make it non case sensitive, I already tried this **`var busqueda = document.getElementById("busqueda").value.toLowerCase();`** but nothing is showing.

**EDIT:** found a solution, maybe is not a fancy one but it works the way I want, thanks!

```
function buscar()
{
    var busqueda = document.getElementById("busqueda").value;

    con.query("SELECT * FROM candidata", function (err, result, fields)
    {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        var tam = result.length;
        var text;

        for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
        {   
                        if
        (
            (busqueda == result[i].nom_can.toLowerCase()) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].nom_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ci_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ape_can.toLowerCase()) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ape_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ocu_can.toLowerCase()) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].ocu_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].email_can.toLowerCase()) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].email_can) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].mun_can.toLowerCase()) 
            || (busqueda == result[i].mun_can)
            || ((busqueda == result[i].nom_can.toLowerCase()+" "+result[i].ape_can.toLowerCase())) 
            || ((busqueda == result[i].nom_can+" "+result[i].ape_can))
        )
        {
                text += '<tbody>';
                text += '<tr>';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].ci_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].nom_can;
                text += ' ';
                text += result[i].ape_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].fky_cat;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].mun_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += result[i].est_can;
                text += '</td>';
                text += '\t\t';
                text += '<td>';
                text += '</td>';
                text += '</tr>';
                text += '</tbody>';
            }   
            document.getElementById("find").innerHTML= text;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why not use `toLowerCase()` before comparing

Comment: Are the results from your database lowercase?

Comment: why not to use WHERE condition in the query?

Comment: @brk I did but it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Mark_M They have the first letter in uppercase. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/nhUNr7K.jpg)

Comment: Well then you need to make both lowercase before comparing. But really you should be doing this in the db query. It wasteful to select * and then filter.

Comment: @Mark_M Doing this **busqueda == result[i].nom_can.toLowerCase()** worked the way I wanted, not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: I'm not sure I underdtand your problem but if you want to make a case insensitive search in your db you can update your table collation to a collation ending in _ci instead of _cs